# I am trying to write 500 records from a json file to DynamoDB table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-dynamodb

I have a sample.json file and I want to dump the data into a DynamoDB table but I keep getting this error - `ValueError: Expected object or value`.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
import boto3
import requests
import json
import re
import json_stream

import pandas as pd
from sys import getsizeof

from datetime import datetime
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
from decimal import Decimal

dynamodb_client = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name="eu-central-1")
url_table = dynamodb_client.Table("URLConfig")
global_config = dynamodb_client.Table("GlobalConfigs")

chunks = pd.read_json("sample.json", lines=True, chunksize = 500)

for c in chunks:
    c = c.to_dict(orient="records")
    try:
        with url_table.batch_writer() as batch:
            for i in range(len(c)):
                c[i]["confidence"] = Decimal(str(c[i]["confidence"]))
                batch.put_item(Item=c[i])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        # records which generated exceptions must be collected in a file.
        # as of now it is being ignored.
        continue
```

Comment: You need to include the basics for troubleshooting - show us the file and the full error message with stacktrace.

Comment: Yep, we definitely need to know what the data looks like. Also, it'd be good to know if it was one single part of the JSON and if so, what about that JSON is different.